# How to inject a variable value into two maven modules in Java?

Tags: java, maven, module

I have one big project with a pom.xml, and several modules within this project that have their own pom.xml's. Two of these modules depend on the same variable (a database name).

Is there an existing pattern to name this variable in one place, and have it injected into the two projects? I imagine there is a maven plugin for this, but could not find one.

The variable would need to be injected into a java file and an xml file

Comment: Sounds like java configuration rather than maven configuration?  If that is the case you sould be thinking about externalised configuration files which are loaded at runtime.

Comment: Why not add a common project? With maven i think you can share properties using say a parent pom.

Comment: You might be right. It just feels wrong to create a whole configuration file when I only need one variable

Comment: You can share properties, but I don't think the pom can pass those properties into a java file

Comment: I'm looking for something where within the java file I can do variable=<some-pattern>, and then at build time maven injects the variable into the file where it sees <some-pattern>. An external configuration file, or some other solution could probably work as well.

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be a Spring project, would it?

Comment: @Noah you are correct, you can inherit properties from your parent pom file, but  afaik there is no way to inject it into your java at runtime.

Comment: @MichaelParker no, this isn't a spring project

Comment: Maybe the properties plugin will be of help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020755/maven-properties-plugin

Comment: In any case, you can always use the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable.  `export MAVEN_OPTS="-D{parameter_name}={parameter-value}"`

Comment: @Noah is there any DI framework available?

Comment: @ConMan I believe we use Dagger

Comment: I edited the question to reflect where the variables need to be injected. The other problem with the external configuration file is that one place this variable needs to be sourced is an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I said this in the comments but I believe that this is what you're looking for.  You can use `MAVEN_OPTS` to specify a variable that gets injected at runtime.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-D{parameter_name}={parameter-value}"
```

So if you wanted a variable called "foo" with a value of "bar", you'd do

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dfoo=bar"
```

To access this variable in your XML file, you'd use `${foo}` (or whatever you called it), like so:

```
<value>classpath:contexts/${foo}.properties</value>
```

(the above is just a snippet from a project I'm working on that uses the same technique)

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to include the variable in our chef deployment, which allows us to deposit it into a configuration file. From there, the Java code is able to access the variable.

The xml file is an Oozie workflow, so I also used chef to deposit the same variable into the Oozie coordinator.

This answer probably won't help anyone trying to solve this issue using only maven, but it is the solution that worked for me.

I do believe java.util.Properties might help if you're only working with Java problems.